# How to find devices via Wi-fi peer 2 peer, that have the same app installed?

Tags: android, wifi, p2p, wifip2p

I am quite new in the Android development. I have an app that tries to connect to other devices running android via Wi-Fi peer 2 peer. What I want to do is to see only the devices that have the same app installed rather than see all the available peers. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you can do this!! :)

Try using the [Wifi P2p for Service Discovery](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct.html). Actually, the link is a training which teaches exactly what you want.

So, what you basically want to do is create a `WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo` object that contains the information you want to advertise or the information that your app broadcasts and then, `addLocalService` which advertises/broadcasts this object.

You also need to discover nearby services which are broadcasting some information. To get the service information, create a `WifiP2pManager.DnsSdServiceResponseListener`. This receives the actual description and connection information. Here, you can read the information and if it is the information your app broadcasts, then *Hooray* you found a nearby device that has your particular application.

**Tip:** You can broadcast some application specific code like "This_is_my_App" and then some device specific information lets say *Wifi MAC Address/DeviceName* which helps you differentiate between different devices which you can populate in a List and display.

Comment: sry for late answer. Thanks a lot for your reply. I'll try this out :)

Comment: @arvind Let me know if it doesn't work... though m sure it will work

Comment: Works like a charm :)