# Detect nearby bluetoooth enabled devices running my app

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-wifi, wifip2p

When I researched about this problem [I came across this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869983/how-to-find-devices-via-wi-fi-peer-2-peer-that-have-the-same-app-installed/33889263) So I know this is possible in [Wifip2p api](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct.html), but I want to achieve the same thing with Bluetooth api. Is it possible? 
In Wifip2p api the app broadcasts some text (let's say the app unique code) that other devices (running the same app) are listening and respond, so I can show the device list running my app. But is it possible to broadcast something to all nearby devices using the bluetooth api?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible. Bluetooth applications follow a typical client/server architecture. See the [official Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ConnectingDevices) for more info.

Comment: I know how to discover nearby bluetooth devices, but what I want is to discover only the devices that have my app installed

Comment: That link describes much more than discovering devices. You would have to write the server and client into your app so that it can connect properly to other devices running your app. The link points to the part dealing with `BluetoothSocket` and `BluetoothServerSocket` which is how to accomplish just that. It's obviously not as high level an interface as WifiP2P, but it's not so different. WifiP2P manages socket communication underneath.

Comment: You can have a look at [Bluetooth LE](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html) if you don't like the socket/server approach. In LE the device to be discovered will "advertise" itself (like a Bluetooth LE beacon) and is then found by another device scanning for Bluetooth LE devices.